# Add new object between each object in an array

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I want to add a new object between each object in an array using **functional programming**. The new object is derived using its two neighbors.

Let’s say that we start with an array of integers `[1,2,3]`, I want to add new integers by adding its neighbors so the resulting array looks like this `[1,3,2,5,3]`

I know of intersperse but that only allows me to add a static element. I also considered chain but that only visits one element at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `R.mapAccum` to create an array that uses the previous item (saved in the accumulator). Take the result of `R.mapAccum`, and use `R.last` to get the array (dropping the accumulator), flatten, and remove the redundant first item:

```js
const { pipe, mapAccum, last, flatten, tail } = R

const fn = pipe(
  mapAccum((a, b) => [b, [a + b, b]], 0),
  last, // take the array of pairs (drop the accumulator)
  flatten, // flatten the array of pairs to an array of numbers
  tail // take all items after the redundant first
)

const numbers = [1, 2, 3]

const result = fn(numbers)

console.log(result) // [1,3,2,5,3]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Vanilla JS - reduce the array to another array. On each iteration, spread the previous accumulator (`acc`), create an item by adding the current number to the previous number on the accumulator (or 0 if none), and also include the current number. Slice redundant first element off.

```js
const fn = (cb, arr) => arr.reduce((acc, n) => 
  [...acc, cb(n,  acc.at(-1) ?? 0), n]
, []).slice(1)

const numbers = [1, 2, 3]

const add = (a, b) => a + b
const result = fn(add, numbers)

console.log(result) // [1,3,2,5,3]
```

Comment: Perfect, that solved it! Just curious, how many times is the list traversed? Is it once for map and once for flatten?

Comment: The complexity of each action in the pipe is O(n), so it's actually O(4n), and since we're ignoring constants it's O(n) total. In other words it traverses the array 4 times, but unless you have huge arrays you won't feel the difference.

Comment: Nice!  But two things:  I think Johan was right about the traversals.  `last` -- via `nth` -- is based on a property access and `tail` -- via `slice` -- is based on `Array.prototype.slice`.  Both should be close to `O (1)`.  Second, the `reduce` version is clean, but what would happen if `cb(a, 0)` would throw an exception?  To fix it, I think you might need the same sort of index-hacking I do in my `flatMap` version... but then you could lose the `.slice` call.

Comment: Yep `nth` is o(1). `Array.proptotype.slice()` creates a new array, so it's o(n). 
Why would `cb(a, 0)` throw an exception?

Answer (score 1):

I played around with some Ramda versions, including one similar to Ori Drori's answer and one that used [`aperture`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#aperture)`(2)`, but nothing was as compelling as this vanilla JS version:

```js
const between = (fn) => (xs) => 
  xs .flatMap ((x, i, a) => i == 0 ? [x] : [fn (a [i - 1], x), x])

const add = (a, b) => a + b

console .log (between (add) ([1, 2, 3]))
```

We could replace `fn (a [i - 1], x)` with `fn (a [i - 1], x, i, a)` if your needs extended beyond working with the two neighbors.  Although at that point, I would probably be looking toward [`scan`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#scan) or [`mapAccum`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mapAccum).

While we could start toward point-free with a version like this:

```js
const between = (fn) => 
  addIndex (chain) ((x, i, a) => i == 0 ? [x] : [fn (a [i - 1], x), x])
```

getting entirely point-free look difficult and likely to obfuscate more than it clarifies.  I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Oh man. This answer will require some time to wrap my head around 

Comment: Nice! I've added another solution that uses reduce.